# No puedo obtener el resultado de una función que estoy llamando desde otro archivo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, module.exports

El problema es que necesito traer los datos de una consulta a mysql, la consulta esta en una funcion que llamo desde otro archivo js pero al momento de ejecutar la funcion me devuelve el valor como undefined en vez de obtener el resultado de la consulta

este es el archivo en el cual llamo la funcion

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
const resultado = require('./base.js');
    
const mostrar = ()=>{
  const data = resultado.ObtenerDatos();
  console.log(data);

}
  boton.addEventListener("click", mostrar);
```

y este es el archivo donde esta la funcion

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');

    function ObtenerDatos(){
      const mysql = require('mysql');
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : null,
      database : 'electron_db'
    });
     
    connection.connect();
    const sql = 'SELECT emp_id,emp_name FROM employee';
    connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) 
     {
      console.log(error.code);
     }else {
         return results;

     }
    });
    connection.end(); 
    }

    module.exports = {
      ObtenerDatos
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `connection.query` es una función asíncrona. Es decir, espera recibir un callback que será invocado al terminar la consulta.

```
connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
  } else {
    return results;
  }
});
```

El `return results` que pones en el callback **jamás podrá ser devuelto** por la función `ObtenerDatos` ya que se encuentra dentro de un callback. Tienes dos opciones:

1. Pasar un callback a `ObtenerDatos`.
2. Usar `promisify` para convertir `connection.query` a una promesa y devolverla.

---

**Pasar un callback a `ObtenerDatos`**

```
function ObtenerDatos(onResults) {
  ...
```

Le pasamos `onResults` como callback a `connection.query`:

```
connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
  } else {
    onResults(results);
  }
});
```

Y lo invocas así:

```
const mostrar = () => {
  resultado.ObtenerDatos(results => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

**Usando `promisify`**

Esta opción puede ser útil si no te gusta mucho usar callbacks (o si no los entiendes aún) para que puedas devolver el resultado de `connection.query` desde `ObtenerDatos`.

```
const makeQuery = promisify(connection.query).
return makeQuery(sql);
```

> Nota: debes importar `promisify` desde el módulo `util`: `const { promisify } = require('util');`.

Y lo invocas de esta forma:

```
const mostrar = async () => {
  const datos = await resultado.ObtenerDatos();
  console.log(datos); // respuesta de la consulta
}
```